Laptop not booting after updating Ubuntu Mate to 24.04
I updated my Ubuntu Mate to 24.04 LTS. After completing the installation process when I Rebooted my laptop it did not boot up. I tried every possible thing which I could have done but nothing is working. After pressing Alt+F2 nothing is working just a _ is blinking on top left corner. Unable to type anything there. Recovery mode is not showing. Please suggest me what should I do I stupidly did not backup.
After pressing esc it is showing this:

It is showing
[Failed]Failed to start cups.service
[Failed]Failed to start Thermald.service
[Failed]Failed to start lightdm.service
[Failed]Failed to start bluetooth.service
[Failed]Failed to start cups.path
[Failed]Failed to listen on cups.socket
[Failed]Failed to start power-profiles-daemon.service
[Failed]Failed to start gpu-manager.service
[***] Job Plymouth-quit-wait.service/start running(timer is running/no limit)```









CTL+ALT+F3 may give you a terminal to work from. If not then you can get the grub menu on boot by asserting ESC during boot. Then try to boot from recovery or a previous kernel. If that doesn't work then select the grub menu option and assert 'e' and remove 'quiet' from the boot script and start the boot. To start to fix this you need to find the first failure and work from there. Alternative: Backup data from a booted install media and do a fresh install.

CTL+ALT+F3 is giving a blank screen with a _ on left top which is blinking. I tried it before also I thought it was terminal but I am unable to type anything there.

Unable to get the grub menu. After asserting ESC during boot it is showing the screen which I have attached with my question. I am unable to do anything I am just stuck in my booting stage and just able to see the failures that I have attached

Can you brief me about the alternative option? Like how to backup data from a installed media and do a fresh install Or you can send me any tutorial of this because I have less knowledge of this

If your computer uses UEFI for booting, press ESC if your computer uses BIOS then press SHIFT. (Don't hold it down but repeatedly assert it.)

The following link is a tutorial for installing 24.04 Desktop OS. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview  If you follow this the installer can be used to trial the OS & to copy off you data to a second USB stick. (It should mount your existing disk.) So, for example, when you boot the installer choose 'Trial' first and use 'Files' (Nautilus) to copy the files.
